# APIs for Integration With Microosft Staff Hub

Tags: ms-office

I am planning to integrate with Microsoft Staff Hub. Are there any APIs available to push data to Staff Hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no public API is available, but there is a closed preview available. You do need to specifically request access though.

https://staffhub.uservoice.com/forums/323718-general/suggestions/16755400-api-access-to-assign-shifts-complete-other-actio